# Setting variable to 0 using if statement

Tags: python, sqlite

Using Sqlite3. Let's say I have this empty table table with no rows. Not one row of data is inserted, completely empty.
c = conn.cursor()

```
       test
-----------------
   amount | date

query = "SELECT SUM (column1) FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN '"+blah+"' AND '"+blah+"'"
c.execute(query)
data = c.fetchall()
if data == None:
   amountsum = 0
else:
   amountsum = data
print(amountsum)
output = (100 - amountsum)
print(output)
```

When I print amountsum, all i get is (None,) which is not 0. For output, it would give me "TypeError: Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
How do set assign 0 to amountsum if date is a 'NoneType'

Comment: try "if not data:" instead of "if data == None:"

Comment: Note that you never execute this query before you fetch any result

Comment: @Nik, hello, "if not data" works as it sets amountsum to 0 but now even if data has values and is not 'NoneType', amountsum is still set to 0.

Comment: `data` will be list in any case. I think there is more code, like the missing `c.execute(query)` that you have now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `fetchall()` `data` will be/is list with one element - tuple - `(None,)`, when date not between the specific dates. So basically `data` is `[(None,)]`
That is why your `if` check does not work.
Use `fetchone()`, to get just one tuple.

```
query = "SELECT SUM(column1) FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN '"+blah+"' AND '"+blah+"'"
c.execute(query)
data = c.fetchone()
if data[0] is None:
   amountsum = 0
else:
   amountsum = data[0]
```

it's better to change your query and use `COALESCE`

```
query = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(column1), 0) FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN '"+blah+"' AND '"+blah+"'"
c.execute(query)
data = c.fetchone()
amountsum = data[0]
```

Comment: I changed it fetchall to fetchone now. Is my else statement correct? When data from c.fetchone is not None, why doesn't my else statement run?

Comment: With `fetchone` you get one-element tuple. Check the examples I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not behaving as desired because a `list` of `tuple` instances representing database records returned by a query is returned by `sqlite3.connect.cursor.fetchall()`, in the case that no records are returned by the query an empty `list` will be returned.

The statement `if data == None:` will never pass in your script as `[] != None`.

You could apply the "`autosum` is query result or `0` if no results present in `data`" logic right after assignment of `data` using the following line.

```py
autosum = 0 if not data else data[0][0]
```

Note how the above accesses the first value within the first `tuple` in the `list` `data`. If we simply wrote `autosum = 0 if not data else data` we would assign the entire `list` if any results are returned instead of the single returned value you seem to be trying to work with.

**`fetchone()`**

Since you are only seeking to access a single query result (at least as far as I can tell from the code you've shared) it would probably be an idea to use `sqlite3.connect.cursor.fetchone()` instead of `sqlite3.cursor.fetchall()`. This will return a `tuple` representing the first query result instead of the `list` of `tuple` instances as with `fetchall()`.

```py
data = c.fetchone()
autosum = 0 if not data else data[0]
```